# Add a column, with a default value, to an existing table in oracle

Tags: oracle, alter

I created a table named- books and have a column in that by the title 'color' . Initially I have null values in the column 'color'. Now, when I run the following query :

```
alter table books modify color default 'blue';
```

schema is formed but on doing select *from books , all the values in column color are still null. What would be the correct query to fire?

here is the link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4210/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course. Alter table just changes the table structure but not the content. New entries will get the default.

To update the existing values run a sql-update query like:

update books set color='blue' where colore is null;

Answer (score 2):

If you now inserting into table then only will come with default values. This statement don't know about previous contents of this table. In non technical language, you are telling oracle to do so now on-wards. This statement will not perform check to old values.

Answer (score 0):

`alter` is ok for the next values to be inserted: try to insert lines without specifying a value for column `color`, value should be blue.

But this does not work for existing values, for which you just need an update:

```
update books set color = 'blue';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this query will be used to add column with default value in existing table in oracle.

```
alter table <table_name> add <column_name> <contraint> default <default_value> not null;
```

example:

```
alter table books add record_status number(1,0) default 1 not null;

alter table books add color varchar(20) default 'blue' not null;
```